# How do I use an ArrayList consisting of NameValuePairs in Nashorn?

Tags: java, nashorn

How do I use an ArrayList consisting of NameValuePair in Nashorn?
For an example I would have something like this in Nashorn:

```
var args = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

But i need it like this ( Java example )

```
List<NameValuePair> args = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

Comment: Are you asking How to read a typed ArrayList inside JS using Nashorn?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of generics is not known by JavaScript, so `new java.util.ArrayList()` is actually the same as `new ArrayList<NameValuePair>()`.

To create such an object in Nashorn, use:

```
final ScriptEngine se = new NashornScriptEngineFactory()
    .getScriptEngine("--language=es6");

// prints [one, two]
se.eval("const ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList');" +
    "const args = new ArrayList();" +
    "args.add('one'); // or an NameValuePair instance" +
    "args.add('two');" +
    "print(args);"
);
```